# Areas vs sum of smaller areas - ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap

I am working with huge regions defined by polygons in the Pacific ocean.

Some polygons can be huge and spread from 140E to 180E and from 10N to 40N for example.
If I calculate the area of this polygon (A0) for example using the Cylindrical Equal Area (World), I get a value in square km.

However, If i split my main polygon in 2 smaller polygons and I calculate the areas of the 2 smaller polygons (A1 & A2) using the same projection, the sum of the 2 areas will be slighty higher than the area of the big unique polygon:

```
A1+A2>A0
```

I would expect to get A1+A2=A0...

I have checked the topology, tried to densify my polygons, checked the snapping of the vertices of my polygons but everything seems to be fine on these sides...

Why do I have such a difference?

Comment: When dealing with huge data you are going to get discrepancies between whole and divided records, this is not a surprise. One of the limitations of projecting data is distortion which is akin to what you're experiencing. Should you need A1 + A2 = A0 you will need to work in geographic coordinates which counters distortion **but** the units are almost useless. To calculate lengths and areas of very large features you should be using geodesic calculations https://community.esri.com/thread/196259-calculate-geodesic-area-of-polygon

Comment: Thank you @MichaelStimson. Using my WGS84 projection, I am now using !shape.area@squarekilometers! in the field calculator to get my areas and get A1+A2=A0. Just to clarify, what would be the difference between a geodesic area and an area obtained from a projection? Is there one more relevant than the other?

Comment: Geodesic calculations take into account the curvature of the earth, or at least a model thereof, projections (by their very nature) do not. Standard euclidean geometry is nice and fast and is generally acceptable for smaller features (city sized or less) depending on the requirement of accuracy, you would only need different calculations if you're absolutely pedantic about length/area *on the ground* or, as in your case, the features are very large.